# What is the proper way to handle exception inside callback?

Tags: java, exception, callback

I've got a callback with exception instance. Currently i handle it this way, but i think that there is a better way. Would like to hear some comment from Java expert. =)

```
...
onError(Exception e) {
   if (e instanceof IOException) {
      ioe = (IOException)e;
      // do smth with ioe
   } else if (e instanceof MyException) {
      mye = (MyException)e;
      // do smth with mye
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about what you mean by "handle exceptions inside callback", but the `onError` method you provided could be better expressed like this:

```
...
onError(Exception e) {
   try {
       throw e;
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
      // do smth with ioe
   } catch (MyException mye) {
      // do smth with mye
   }
}
...
```

Comment: +1 That is neat. And note that re-throwing an exception is a cheap and safe operation. In particular, it does not create a new stacktrace or alter the exception object in any way.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this. Won't rethrow cause performance descrease?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you run your program with the instsnceof solution, and then with the rethrow solution and see how many % the execution time differs :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could override "onError" with subclasses of exceptions:

```
interface MyExceptionHandler  
{
    onError(Exception e) {
          // Default exception
    }
    onError(IOException ioe) {
          // do smth with ioe
    }
    onError(MyException mye) {
          // do smth with mye
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a try with multiple catch blocks, each catch block dealing with a narrower exception than the one after him, this way you no longer need the boiler plate code with the ifs:

```
try {
   doSomething();    
} catch(IOException ioe) {
   log.error("File not found"+ioe.getmessage();
} catch(Exception e) {
   //... etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, Im recieving exception as parameter.